# Why does a white glossy sphere take much longer to render as same sphere in black?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

Assembly yourself a simple scene like this one. That's a 4K texture in the background.

14.92 seconds for black
24.73 seconds for white
[image]
[image: Simple scene containing sphere with a subdivision modifier]

Comment: I would suspect that diffuse rays never need to be evaluated, because there is no chance of black reflecting anything.  If that suspicion is correct, then you'd see even a 0.01 gray sphere taking as long to render as a 1.0 white sphere.  But I haven't tested, and there is plenty of room for errors in testing (like render order and persistent data.)

Comment: Why can't you just share this "simple scene" to test against? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: The scene has poliigon textures and it doesn't "pack well". Guys, how about try it yourself in ANY scene and then we'll get specific about how this Bermuda triangle of a scene is causing the render anomalies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that just like in real life, the color of an object is the certain light that the object reflects. So a white colored object is going to reflect most of the light, hence more calculations (ray bounces) are needed to find the color of a pixel. While the black object is going to absorb most of the light, so less calculations are needed.

I set up a similar scene, and while my results weren't as dramatic as yours, you can notice a similar trend.

[image]

Comment: Well, if the compositor could replace colors then I would just make it white in post and save some serious time on animations.